# C program-fork command in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, fork

I am writing a C program that uses a fork command and loops 10 times, at the same time, the process ID will be displayed in each loop.

Following are my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main ()
{ int x;
  for(x=0;x<10;x++)
  {
   fork();
   printf("The process ID (PID): %d \n",getpid());
  }
}
```

My codes generate numerous of process ID,is there anything wrong in the program?

Comment: You should post, or at least describe in more detail, the output you get, and say what you expected to get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fork()` system call creates a child which executes the same code as the parent.  From that moment, there are 2 processes executing the next line: parent and child.  Each of them executes the `printf()`.

The second time the `for` loop is executed, it is executed by the parent **and the child**: each of them execute `fork()`, and so from that moment there are 4 processes: the 2 first ones, and their new children.

So, for every iteration in the loop you are doubling the number of processes.  The total number of processes is thus 2^10 = 1024.

So, the `printf()` inside the `for` loop is executed:

- 10 times for the first 2 processes
- 9 times for their children (2 processes)
- 8 times for the next generation (4 new children)
- 7 times for the next one (8 children)
- 6 times fot the next one (16 children)
- 5 times for the next one (32 children)
- 4 times for the next one (64 children)
- 3 times for the next one (128 children)
- 2 times for the next one (256 children)
- 1 time for the last one (512 children)

Total: 10*2 + 9*2 + 8*4 + 7*8 + 6*16 + 5*32 + 4*64 + 3*128 + 2*256 + 1*512 = 2046.

The `printf()` is executed 2046 times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This clear my doubts.
I would like to modify the program above to display a message that it is either a parent process or a child process, is it possible?

Comment: `fork()` returns 0 to the child, and a number greater than zero to the parent if the call was successful.  So you can do, for example, `i = fork();` and then `if (i==0) printf("I am a child.\n");`

Comment: Appreciate if you could help in my other question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876290/c-programming-scanf-not-working-in-ubuntu
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check my exemple

```
  pid_t pID = fork();
       if (pID == 0)                // child
       {
          // Code only executed by child process

          sIdentifier = "Child Process: ";
          globalVariable++;
          iStackVariable++;
    }
        else if (pID < 0)            // failed to fork
        {
            cerr << "Failed to fork" << endl;
            exit(1);
            // Throw exception
        }
        else                                   // parent
        {
          // Code only executed by parent process

          sIdentifier = "Parent Process:";
        }

        // Code executed by both parent and child.
```